# How to interact with a person who replies an email from Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm going to send an email from Marketing Cloud and whenever a person replies that email, I will need to update a case related with that person in Salesforce CRM. Is there a way to do that?
I think I can use `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject`  to update the case, however I have no idea how to find out who replied the email.
I really appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks in advance.

**Update**:
I created a sender profile with custom RMM settings (using "Forward using triggered send") and add an AMPscript block to the Email for logging reply details like Ali's suggestion.

```
%%[
Set @SubscriberKey = _RMM_RecipientSubscriberKey
Set @Subject = _RMM_ReplySubject
Set @Email = _RMM_RecipientEmailAddress
Set @Reply = _replycontent

InsertDE('Catch RMM reply', 'SubscriberKey', @SubscriberKey, 'Email', @Email, 'Subject', @Subject, 'Reply', @Reply)
]%%
```

After I reply the email, it did forward the email and inserted a record to the "Catch RMM reply" DE. However it shows nothing.
[image]

The record was already inserted but couldn't display. Not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a sender profile by customizing Reply Mail Management settings and then use Triggered Sends for email forwarding. Inside Trigger Sends email, you can put a script that logs all the details into a DE.

Check for RMM strings [here](https://ampscript.guide/system-strings/).

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ali's suggestion, eventually this is what I did:

- Activate RMM (if it isn't active then it will merely forward the email)
- Create a DE to store replies (may not need, in case we only want to update the case in CRM)
- Create an email to log the reply and execute action (e.g update case/insert into the Catch RMM reply DE)
- Create a trigger send definition which using the email
- Create a custom sender profile with "Forward using triggered send"

Due to RMM personalization strings can't capture the variable in the original message. Therefore I secretly added a hidden html block to fetch the case Id, I can't use lookup function for that because a person may have more than a case.

Then the original email will have an additional html block something like this:

```
<table id="" style="display:none;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
        [[[Populate my case ID here]]]
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The forward email for logging information, will be like this:

```
%%[
Set @SubscriberKey = _RMM_RecipientSubscriberKey
Set @Subject = _RMM_ReplySubject
Set @Email = _RMM_RecipientEmailAddress
Set @Reply = _RMM_ReplyBodyText

InsertDE('Catch RMM reply', 'SubscriberKey', @SubscriberKey, 'Email', @Email, 'Subject', @Subject, 'Reply', @Reply)

Set @caseRegEx = '[[]{3}(.*)[]]{3}'
Set @caseId = RegExMatch(@Reply, @caseRegEx, 1)
/* update action here */
UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Case', @caseId, 'Description', 'Updated')
]%%
%%_RMM_ReplyBodyHTML%%
```

If anyone has a better idea, then I'm all ears. Thank you.